# What is the relation between Spring-boot's support for quartz and @EnableScheduling/@Scheduled Annotation

Tags: spring-boot, quartz

Is there any relation between the functionality provided by `@EnableScheduling` in Spring and the default autoconfiguration for Quartz in Spring-Boot?

I mean, are the methods annotated with `@Scheduled` supposed to interact with Quartz in any way, or are they simply scheduled separately (and locally)?

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked the Spring-Quartz integration – no, you couldn’t use the @Scheduled annotation and delegate to Quartz. Here documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html

Answer (score 1):

The task scheduling based on `@EnableScheduling` works independently of Quartz.
Depending on your requirements, you can use just [Spring task scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-task-execution-scheduling) or [quartz scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-quartz). However there does not seem to have an integration between both.